# AutoCAD VBA acadPViewport unpredictable behaviour when setting standardscale

Tags: vba, autocad

I have a VBA script that imports a layout into an exsting drawing, its a paperspace layout and contains one acadPViewport to view the model with.

I need to set a sensible default view, the easiest way to do this is to set the viewport to the extents of the model.

I can do this by calling:

```
VP.standardscale = acVPScaleToFit
'(optional, I've tried adding these to no effect)
VP.update
currentDocument.Regen
```

I've experimented and this code call. If I find the viewport in the immediate window, while not running any macros or routines, by referencing:

```
ThisDrawing.ActiveLayout.block(1).standardscale = acvpscaletofit
```

it has the desired effect of calling ZoomExtents within the pViewport (as far as I can tell it recenters and recalculates the extents, which is what I'm looking for).

When I run exactly the same code inside my main code it has no effect.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, it turns out, is that many features of AutoCAD won't work if the main application is off-screen, hidden, minimised or was at file load.